# How to load/show the Desktop from C# code after booting into a non-Desktop shell?

Tags: c#, windows

I have an application that I boot as the shell instead of booting to the desktop of Windows. So after booting there is no Desktop visible at all. Sometimes during troubleshooting I need to access the Desktop. In Windows 7 I just ran Process.Start("explorer") and the Desktop would appear. However in Windows 10 this just opens an explorer window and not the Desktop. However, if I open Task Manager and select File/Run New Task and enter "explorer" it opens the Desktop. So it seems possible. But how can I mimic what the Task Manager is doing in my C# application? I need to be able to load/show the Desktop through C# code in Windows 10 like I used to be able to do in Windows 7.

NOTE: Using Task Manager (as described above) to show the Desktop is not possible since these are single purpose PCs without a keyboard (which would be required).

My code is as follows:

```
Process Proc = new Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";
Proc.Start();
```

Comment: I think it depends how you set your application up as the shell https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions, are you using assigned access?

Comment: My app is a classic Windows app, so I am not using assigned access. I am setting the registry value for "HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my observations launching `explorer.exe` will give you a desktop only if the registry key `HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` is set to `explorer.exe` (at least on XP and Win7 up to SP1). Try setting the the registry key value to exlorer prior to spawning the new process, afterwards you can set it back to your application.
If that doesn't work, try launching `userinit.exe` instead of `explorer.exe`. 
Also note that there's sometimes a slight delay before the write to the registry is seen by readers, inserting a `Thread.Sleep` for half a second should take care of that.

Comment: Will give your suggestions a try later when I am able. I would still like to determine how to mimic what Task Manager does, as it starts the Desktop simply as desired.

Comment: This answer worked! However, instead of setting the Shell to explorer.exe I just deleted the shell value completely. I believe that is the default for Windows anyway. Then I ran "userinit.exe" which loaded the Desktop and then I put the shell value back for my application.